# Can this integrability assumption be weakened in a way that the stochastic integration by parts still holds?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales

$\newcommand{\Ex}{\mathbb E} \newcommand{\diff}{~\mathrm d}$Recently, I have read the integration by parts formula for a continuous semi-martingale in these [notes](https://ipgold.epfl.ch/%7Eleveque/Lecture_Notes/sc2_final.pdf).

> **Theorem** Let $X$ and $Y$ be continuous semi-martingales such that
> $$
> \Ex \bigg [ \int_0^t (X_s + Y_s)^2 \diff \langle X + Y \rangle_s \bigg ] <\ \infty \quad \forall t \ge 0. \quad \quad (\star)
> $$
> Then
> $$
> X_t Y_t - X_0 Y_0 = \int_0^t X_s \diff Y_s + \int_0^t Y_s \diff X_s + \langle X, Y \rangle_t
> \quad \text{a.s.} \quad \forall t \ge 0.
> $$
> **Proof** Let $f(x):=x^2$. Then $f'(x) = 2x$ and $f''(x)=2$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$. Notice that $Z _t :=X_t+Y_t$ is a continuous semi-martingale. By Itô's lemma,
> $$
> \begin{align}
> (X_t+Y_t)^2 - (X_0+Y_0)^2 &= 2 \int_0^t (X_s+Y_s) \diff (X_s+Y_s)+\langle X+Y\rangle_t, \\
> (X_t-Y_t)^2 - (X_0-Y_0)^2 &= 2 \int_0^t (X_s-Y_s) \diff (X_s-Y_s)+\langle X-Y\rangle_t.
> \end{align}
> $$
> Subtracting these two formulas gives:
> $$
> 4 X_t Y_t-4 X_0 Y_0=4 \int_0^t X_s \diff Y_s+4 \int_0^t Y_s \diff X_s + (\underbrace{\langle X+Y\rangle_t - \langle X-Y\rangle_t}_{=4\langle X, Y\rangle_t} ),
> $$
> which completes the proof.

---

The integrability condition $(\star)$ is imposed so that the required hypothesis of Itô's lemma is satisfied.

> Can $(\star)$ be weakened in a way that the integration by parts still holds?

---

**Related definition:** Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P)$ be a probability space and $\mathfrak F = (\mathcal{F}_t, t \ge 0)$ a filtration.

Let $M$ be a continuous square-integrable martingale w.r.t. $\mathfrak F$. Then $M^2$ is a continuous sub-martingale w.r.t. $\mathfrak F$. By Doob's decomposition theorem, there exists a unique continuous increasing process $\langle M \rangle$ adapted to $\mathfrak F$ such that $\langle M \rangle_0 = 0$ a.s. and that $M^2 - \langle M \rangle$ is a continuous martingale w.r.t. $\mathfrak F$. Then $\langle M \rangle$ is called the **quadratic variation** of $M$.

A process $X$ is called a **continuous semi-martingale** w.r.t. $\mathfrak F$ is that can be written as $X_t = M_t+V_t$ where

- $M$ is a continuous square-integrable martingale w.r.t. $\mathfrak F$.
- $V$ is a continuous process that has bounded variation and is adapted to $\mathfrak F$ such that $V_0 = 0$ a.s.

Then the **quadratic variation** of $X$ is defined as
$$
\langle X \rangle := \langle M \rangle.
$$

Let $H$ be a continuous adapted process such that
$$
\mathbb E \bigg [ \int_0^t H_s^2 \mathrm d \langle X \rangle_s \bigg ] < \infty \quad \forall t\ge 0.
$$

Then the **stochastic integral** of $H$ with respect to $X$ is defined as
$$
(H \cdot X)_t := \int_0^t H_s \mathrm d X_s := \underbrace{\int_0^t H_s \mathrm d M_s}_{\text{Itô's integral}} + \underbrace{\int_0^t H_s \mathrm d V_s}_{\text{Riemann-Stieltjes's integral}}.
$$

> **Itô's lemma.** Let $X$ be a continuous semi-martingale and $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ twice continuously differentiable such that
> $$
> \mathbb E \bigg [ \int_0^t (f'(X_s))^2 \mathrm d \langle X \rangle_s \bigg ] < \infty \quad \forall t\ge 0.
> $$
> Then for all $t \ge 0$,
> $$
> f(X_t)-f(X_0) = \int_0^t f'(X_s) \mathrm d X_s + \frac{1}{2} \int_0^t f''(X_s) \mathrm d \langle X \rangle_s 
> \quad \text{a.s.}
> $$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your condition (*) is completely unnecessary. Both the integration by part and Itô's formulas hold true for continuous semi-martingales. There is no need to add any kind of integrability condition.

I suspect the lectures notes introduce these because they want to stay in the realm of $L^2$-martingales.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion for a book with a treatment you mentioned? The classical books (*Continuous Martingales and Brownian Motion* by Revuz/Yor, *Brownian Motion And Stochastic Calculus by Karatzas*) is very hard for me.

Comment: The Revuz-Yor book is indeed advanced. A good reference for students would be for instance Brownian Motion, Martingales, and Stochastic Calculus by Jean-François le Gall.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!